# Referring to two distinct union elements in a single statement

Tags: c++, unions

Say I have a union defined as follows

```
union {
  std::string_view s;
  int i;
};
```

and a function of the form

```
int f(std::string_view);
```

Is it valid to write

```
i = f(s);
```

(assuming we don't care about `s` being in an invalid state after this line)

or does this result in undefined behavior and one would have to write

```
int tmp = f(s);
i = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), with assignment to built-in types like `int`, that is valid since C++11:

> 8. The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator and of all built-in compound assignment operators is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of both left and right arguments, and is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning the reference to the modified object)

Since C++17, thatʼs valid even for assignment to non-built-in types:

> 20. In every simple assignment expression E1 = E2 and every compound assignment expression E1 @= E2, every value computation and side effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1